# Typo3 (sr_feuser_register): Send email to user on admin approval

Tags: email, typo3, typoscript

I'm using the Typo3 extension `sr_feuser_register`. There are several email options available depending on the configuration of the user registration process.

In my case I set:

```
plugin.tx_srfeuserregister_pi1 {
    enableAdminReview = 1
    enableEmailConfirmation = 0
    # ...
}
```

I miss an option to send an email to the user on admin approval (with having users confirmation disabled).

Have I overlooked something?

**[Update]** 
It looks as if the problem doesn't directly result from an incorrect plugin configuration because the email is sent in some cases.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to set the constant enableEmailOnApprove to 1 ?

This send an email to the frontend user after aproval by the admin.

Comment: Yes, I've tried that, but the documentation says it is there to "Enable email on approval. If set, an email will be sent to the front end user when he confirms his registration. **Effective only if email confirmation request is enabled.**"

Comment: Have you checked if a hook is available for the confirmation request sending function. You can disable the sending and activate the confirmation.